# Jquery toggle not working with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, slider

I have a div that is hidden until clicking on a link and then it toggles into view. My code was working fine until I implemented a larger piece of javascript to implement a slider that eases back and forth with mouse movement within the hidden div. My question is how can I combine these two codes (the old and the new) effectively. Right now, I can only get everything to work correctly if the div is not hidden.

```
$("#media").click(function () {
     $("#mediadetails").toggle(2000, function() {
});
$("#mediaclose").click(function() {
     $("#mediadetails").toggle(2000);
})
```

***javascript for slider***

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$mediadetails = $("#mediadetails");
$thumbScroller = $("#thumbScroller");
$thumbScroller_container = $("#thumbScroller .container");
$thumbScroller_content = $("#thumbScroller .content");
$thumbScroller_thumb = $("#thumbScroller .thumb");

$(window).load(function() {

    sliderLeft = $thumbScroller_container.position().left;
    padding = $mediadetails.css("paddingRight").replace("px", "");
    sliderWidth = $(window).width() - padding;
    $thumbScroller.css("width", sliderWidth);
    var totalContent = 0;

    //get content width
    $thumbScroller_content.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        totalContent += $this.innerWidth();
        $thumbScroller_container.css("width", totalContent);
    });

    //content scrolling
    $thumbScroller.mousemove(function(e) {
        if ($thumbScroller_container.width() > sliderWidth) {
            var mouseCoords = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
            var mousePercentX = mouseCoords / sliderWidth;
            var destX = -(((totalContent - (sliderWidth)) - sliderWidth) * (mousePercentX));
            var thePosA = mouseCoords - destX;
            var thePosB = destX - mouseCoords;
            var animSpeed = 900; //ease amount
            var easeType = "easeOutCirc";
            if (mouseCoords > destX) {
                //$thumbScroller_container.css("left",-thePosA);
                //without easing
                $thumbScroller_container.stop().animate({
                    left: -thePosA
                }, animSpeed, easeType);

                //with easing
            } else if (mouseCoords < destX) {
                //$thumbScroller_container.css("left",thePosB); //without easing
                $thumbScroller_container.stop().animate({
                    left: thePosB
                }, animSpeed, easeType);

                //with easing
            } else {
                $thumbScroller_container.stop();
            }
        }
    });

    //thumbnails mouse over/out & initial state
    var fadeSpeed = 200;

    $thumbScroller_thumb.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 0.4);
    });

    $thumbScroller_thumb.hover(

    function() { //mouse over
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 1);
    }, function() { //mouse out
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 0.4);
    });
});

//browser resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    //$thumbScroller_container.css("left",sliderLeft); //without easing
    $thumbScroller_container.stop().animate({
        left: sliderLeft
    }, 400, "easeOutCirc"); //with easing
    var newWidth = $(window).width() - padding;
    $thumbScroller.css("width", newWidth);
    sliderWidth = newWidth;
});
    </script>
```

Comment: What you are really suppose to do? what you are expecting by combined these two together?

Comment: Right now, the slider only toggles correctly (meaning it shows all images instead of stacking them on on top of another) when the div is not hidden. I am assuming this conflict has something to do with that large script.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge JavaScript not working for hidden content.That's why it works for unhidden content. so we need to unhide div before your large scripts take place.

Okay Try this,
Change your larger scripts `$(window).load(function() {//your script});` to any function as for example `function my_slider(){//your script}` (this will disables the executing slider at document load)
And call that function inside your toggling script like

```
$("#media").click(function () {
     $("#mediadetails").toggle(2000, function() {
my_slider();
});
$("#mediaclose").click(function() {
     $("#mediadetails").toggle(2000);
})
```

What we did is rather calling your slider `onload` we execute it, once you click the hidden div to unhide.

Try this if it make sense to you

Comment: Thank you-- how do I write that? delete $(window).load(function() and replace like this? .myslider(function() {  ???

Comment: instead of using display:none; I have changed the css to bottom:-400px;  and then added a new class called "mediaheight" to the toggling script so it reads like: $("#media").click(function () {
$("#mediadetails").addClass("mediaheight").toggle(2000, function() {
  });  This displays everything correctly, but the toggling is a bit erratic-- when you click on "media" the div flashes for an instant and then disappears, but the second time you click on media it works correctly. Any idea how I can change this toggling script to work better?

Comment: I've made some progress with: $("#mediadetails").toggleClass("mediaheight", function() {
  });  Now how can I adjust it so it toggles at a speed of 2000?

Comment: I've tried: $("#mediadetails").toggleClass("mediaheight", 5000); but the toggle still just pops unto the screen for some reason

Comment: Found another solution: $("#mediadetails").animate({height:"600px"}, 1000); I guess I will use this, but I really wanted that toggling effect. Regardless, thanks for helping out!

Comment: I think you have jammed your script now. Advise from me is to go to the basics. you know that your toggling part is working well without slider script.What i suggest is just remove the toggling script and use slider script and try to display it as you want without toggling effect(i mean #mediadetails should display as you want).if it works then after use your toggling effect for #mediadetails